# SQL Server query slow using "left join" and "WHERE field IS NULL"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

First of all I don't have permission to view the execution plan, that is why I'm not sharing it, if I can get those permissions I'll add it later.

I am running a query in SQL Server 2012, something like this, this is just to illustrate the problem, the real fields name make this more complicated to understand.

```
SELECT columns
FROM
    (SELECT column1, column2 
     FROM table1 
     WHERE column3 = condition) AS a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.a = b.b
LEFT JOIN c ON a.c = c.c
LEFT JOIN d ON a.d = d.d
LEFT JOIN e ON a.e=e.e
WHERE 
    e.column IS NULL
```

Without `e.column IS NULL`, it returns around 200 rows, filtered it returns around 100.

Now the question, if I remove `WHERE e.column IS NULL`, it executes in 8 seconds, if I add the `WHERE`, it takes more than 35 seconds.

If I use a temporary table to store the result and then filter the temporary table it takes < 1 second (obviously).

Any idea of why the IS NULL comparison is taking so long with so little rows?
I hope I make myself clear.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the stats of all the tables up to date. Any additional condition is going to increase the cost. Try using not exists instead of checking e.field IS NULL

Comment: can you post the execution plan with and without the `where e.e is null`?

Comment: @gordy sorry, as I said I don't have permission to view the execution plan. Working on getting it.

Comment: Well...until having the execution plan I "solved" it (70% less time) by using in the first select LEN(column) as test, and then adding an outer SELECT with "where test IS NULL", if I use the column as it comes it's slower.
I tried using ISNULL() but it's slower...now I need to look at the execution plan, NEED to know what is happening behind this, to solve it in a proper way.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the actual execution plan all we can do is to speculate.

My *guess* is the join sequence changes if you add or not the condition. If E has many-many rows this can have a huge impact.

1. **Without** the condition the join sequence **could be**:

   - A
   - Then B
   - Then C
   - Then D
   - Then E

   If E has millions of rows it doesn't make the SQL slow since it's already prefiltered by A and access E by an index.
2. **With** the condition the join sequence **could be**:

   - E
   - Then A
   - Then B
   - Then C
   - Then D

   In this case if E has millions or rows, the condition will need to evaluate ALL rows on E, then go to A, and the rest. This is much slower.

But, again, this is just a guess.

Comment: Thank you, I&#39;m using the where to filter after the join, so I have everything on one table that isn&#39;t in another. Doesn&#39;t it suppose to run after all joins? Filtering only 200 rows?
 Thank you!